# Have separate post for each question or a single page for all related questions?

Tags: usability, seo

I have developed a website using WordPress, wherein I post interview questions and their answers.

Now my dilemma is say I have 10 questions and answers I want to post on the "Core Java" topic. Do I post all 10 in a single page, or do I post each of these questions as a single post so that when someone searches for say a question "what is java...." the chances of them coming on single page is way more than showing an entire page of questions and their question being one in this list.

I am very confused about this. I tried to look at how the many other interview Q&A websites do this. Most of them have a separate page for each question, but this makes it difficult for someone who wants to quickly read all related questions and answers, for example.

What do you guys think about this?

Comment: Really depends on how much content you expect each answer to potentially contain. If enough to warrant a dedicated page then this will hold more weight but if it is just a paragraph or so, I'd be inclined to keep them all on one page.

Answer (score 1):

What astonishes me a bit is that it sounds as if this would be all about SEO only. My concern with the one-question-per-page approach is that **you're tearing apart a single interview into a set of seemingly unrelated questions and answers, but this actually pulls these out of their context**. It all depends on the type of interview, of course, but even if it's mainly non-personal, technical Q&A I would still consider the entire thing to be a single context.

I would thus **try a mixed approach**: if someone visits your site, he'll see the interview on a single page, possibly with paging if there are too many questions to fit on one page. Then, I would **offer a separate, question-by-question view for the search engines only**, so that these get indexed properly and get a good ranking. I would then still tie these individual pages together or link them back to the full interview to ensure that a visitor can keep on reading.

Answer (score 0):

In a single page solution, you can also use :

- A summary in top of the page, to list all questions with simple link to the rights anchor
- An accordion, with questions as headings and expendable answers
- A two columns navigation, with questions on the first column and answers on the second. The second depends of where the user clicks on the first (a kind of side menu of questions, but it can be unpleasant if you have already a side menu)

If you think users will go on these pages mainly by a search engine, it may be interesting to add a "return to main topic" (with all questions link list) and "related questions" links.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 10 questions, you should stick to single page with anchors so users can peruse the whole thing in one go if they need to. This is efficiency of providing the information to the user.

Advanced users can also afford to use "Find on Page".

Be sure to include also a back to top link so users can return to the summary of questions.

Example:
[image: faq]

Comment: Actually there will not always be 10 questions, some topics may have 10, some 40, some 20.